# “None of [Index(['', ''], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]” in plotting a Line Plots using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a line using the data of [Canada Immigration](https://www.kaggle.com/roshansharma/immigration-to-canada-ibm-dataset). My code is below...

```
import pandas as pd

df_canada = pd.read_excel('Canada.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Canada by Citizenship (2)') 


df_canada.set_index('OdName', inplace = True)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

years = list (map(str, range(1980, 2014)))
df_canada['Total'] = df_canada[1980] + df_canada[1981]+ df_canada[1982]+ df_canada[1983]+ df_canada[1984]+ df_canada[1985]+ df_canada[1986]+ df_canada[1987]+ df_canada[1988]+ df_canada[1989]+ df_canada[1990]+ df_canada[1991]+ df_canada[1992]+ df_canada[1993]+ df_canada[1994]+ df_canada[1995]+ df_canada[1996]+ df_canada[1997]+ df_canada[1998]+ df_canada[1999]+ df_canada[2000]+ df_canada[2001]+ df_canada[2002]+ df_canada[2003]+ df_canada[2004]+ df_canada[2005]+ df_canada[2006]+ df_canada[2007]+ df_canada[2008]+ df_canada[2009]+ df_canada[2010]+ df_canada[2011]+ df_canada[2012] + df_canada[2013] 


df_canada.loc['Haiti', years].plot(kind = 'line')

plt.title('Immigration from Albania')
plt.ylabel('Number of Immigrants')
plt.xlabel('years')

plt.show()
```

But the code is getting the error "KeyError: "None of [Index(['1980', '1981', '1982', '1983', '1984', '1985', '1986', '1987', '1988',\n       '1989', '1990', '1991', '1992', '1993', '1994', '1995', '1996', '1997',\n       '1998', '1999', '2000', '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006',\n       '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013'],\n      dtype='object')] are in the [index]"" executing  the line "df_canada.loc['Haiti', years].plot(kind = 'line')"

Can anyone help me to correct the code??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution to your problem. You can always use `iloc` to access the columns through numbers:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  
df_canada = pd.read_excel('Canada.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Canada by Citizenship (2)')

#summing all the years in one line instead of typing years individually. Years start from column 9.
df_canada['total'] = df_canada.iloc[:,9:].sum(axis=1)

#Filtering the data country in standard pandas style and select column 9 to second last column (last column is total)
df_canada[df_canada['OdName']=='Haiti'].iloc[:,9:-1].T.plot(kind = 'line')


plt.title('Immigration from Haiti')
plt.ylabel('Number of Immigrants')
plt.xlabel('years')
plt.legend(['number'])
plt.show()
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: I don't know why this didn't get more votes, but your solution amount dozens of others that did not work, finally solved the issue for me. Thank you!!

Comment: @ES Thanks for the kind words mate! Glad I could help. Thanks for the upvote. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You've converted your list `years` to be a list of strings (e.g. `["1980", 1981", ...]`) however it appears the your the columns in your dataframe are years as integers (e.g. 1980 - NOT "1980"). Try changing your `years` variable to simply be `years = list(range(1980, 2014))`

Additionally you can simplify your `total` calculation as well.

```
import pandas as pd

df_canada = pd.read_excel('Canada.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Canada by Citizenship (2)') 


df_canada.set_index('OdName', inplace = True)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Change years to be integers instead of strings
years = list(range(1980, 2014)) 

# Simply sum across the years using our list of years instead of manually typing each year
df_canada['Total'] = df_canada[years].sum(axis=1) 


df_canada.loc['Haiti', years].plot(kind = 'line')

plt.title('Immigration from Albania')
plt.ylabel('Number of Immigrants')
plt.xlabel('years')

plt.show()
```